# EF select parents only if all children have certain status

Tags: entity-framework

I want to select only those parents whose `all` children have status = `success`
I also want to include these children for filtered parents

So the corresponding SQL statement  that returns expected result is

```
select * from Parent p 
join Child c on c.ParentId = p.ParentId
where c.Status = 'success'
```

I want to write the same using EF

```
  var result = await _dbcontext.Parents
            .Where(x => x.Children.All(y => y.Status == "success"))
            .ToListAsync();
```

this is not working

**Update 1**
Sorry the SQL statement above is also not working as expected.

it should only return those parents whose all children have status `success`. So if parent has 5 children and 4 children have `success` and 1 does not have `success` then it should not return that parent

**Update 2**
I have already disabled the lazy loading

```
        dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;// turn-off loading on-demand
        dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;// turn-off dynamic proxy class generation
```

For the time being lets not include children in the select and only filter the parents. So the following EF query

```
 var result = await _dbcontext.Parents                
        .Where(x => x.Children.All(y => y.Status == "success"))
        .ToListAsync();
```

generates the following SQL

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[ParentId] AS [ParentId],         
    [Extent1].[DocumentName] AS [DocumentName],     
    [Extent1].[CreatedDateTime] AS [CreatedDateTime], 
    [Extent1].[ModifiedDateTime] AS [ModifiedDateTime],     
    FROM [dbo].[Parent] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Child] AS [Extent2]
        WHERE ([Extent1].[ParentId] = [Extent2].[ParentId]) AND (('success' <> [Extent2].[Status]) OR (CASE WHEN ('success' = [Extent2].[Status]) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ('success' <> [Extent2].[Status]) THEN cast(0 as bit) END IS NULL))
    )
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? What behavior are you seeing? Also, your corresponding SQL statement would return results if ANY child had a status of "success", and would produce a cartesian product if more than one child for a parent had that state, fyi.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL statement is not correct, you will get all Parents that has at least one childres with the "success" status. But this is not the main point.

As you don't share your model this could it be an eager\lazy load problem. Looks like your EF expression is logically ok. So could you try in this way:

```
var result = await _dbcontext.Parents.Include(x => x.Children).
        .Where(x => x.Children.All(y => y.Status == "success"))
        .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Did you try with my code? Take care of the "Include" method call.

Answer (score 0):

I think i found it. I also have to check if parent has any children. My code was returning parents that does not have any children

```
var result = await _dbcontext.Parents
                .Include(x=>x.Children)                
                .Where(x => x.Children.Any() && x.Children.All(y => y.Status == "success"))
                .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not select all successful Children, and get their Distinct Parents:

```
var result = dbContext.Children                  // get all children
   .Where(child => child.Status == "success")    // keep only the successful ones
   .Select(child => child.Parent);               // select their parents
   .Distinct();                                  // remove duplicate parents
```

For this you need to have setup a [proper one-to-many relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) in entity framework.

```
class Parent
{
    ...
    // a parent has many children:
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children {get; set;}
}

class Child
{
    ...
    // A Child belongs to one parent via foreign key
    public int ParentId {get; set;}
    public virtual Parent Parent {get; set;}
}
```